# Business model: proprietary licensing over service subscription

Tags: security, subscription, saas, license-key

I would like to understand what makes a company prefer to sell licenses for their software with expiration date (e.g. 6 months) over offering a subscription plan that let's user decide when to stop using the software. These models seems to be more alike than they are different, so why issue a license key at all? As there are different understandings of what these models are, let me give you an example that will show what I have in mind when I use these terms.

**Proprietary software licensing business model**. Suppose a company that sells licenses of their software with expiration date of 6 months from the purchase date. The license per installation, meaning that if the user wants to use the software in 5 machines, they will pay for 5 licenses. To move one license from one machine to another, the user has to uninstall it from the first one first. That way the company always knows which licenses are being used and which are not.

**Service subscription business model**. It seems to me that this can be slightly improved with this model. The user registers in the company website and subscribes to their service. The service allows them to use the software in 5 machines. To prevent the user from using the software in more machines than their subscription plan allows them, everytime it lauches the software in one machine the subscription server checks if the user is running too many instances of the software (just like Netflix does when you log in multiple devices). If they are, this can be prevented in a number of ways, like prompting the user to choose a machine to be "replaced" with this new one. That way user can have the software installed in many machines. They just cannot use it in too many machines at one moment.

Maybe there are some security drawbacks of the second model that makes some companies adopt the first one, hence this question.

Comment: This topic is not a topic that fits Stack Overflows criteria. Sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question is about business model dynamics rather than about any code based problem. The Asker should take this question to a more Business-Management orientated Stack Exchange website.

Comment: Would you change your vote if I remove the innacuracies you pointed out? I would still like an answer :)

Comment: Sorry, but this topic isn't about a coding problem. It relates to programming only in an incidental aspect. This is simply the wrong place to ask this type of question, If you can rephrase the question to be much more heavily about coding structure then yes, the vote to close could be removed. Thanks.

Comment: [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169515/what-is-the-best-stack-exchange-site-where-business-related-questions-can-be-ask) may be of interest to you